# Need help with MS Access and RichTextBox's

Tags: .net

Basically, I am displaying a time table of booked rooms. I have 25 RickTextBox's on my form and I set up this loop to get the data from a database for the bookings:

```
cn = New OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0; Data Source=F:\Project\database.mdb;")
cn.Open()
' Looping for two weeks in advance
For x = 0 To 13
    cmd = New OleDbCommand("SELECT bs1.teacher, bs1.date, bs1.period FROM(" & cbRoom.Text.ToLower & ") WHERE(((bs1.date) = #" & current & "#)) ORDER BY bs1.period;", cn)
    dr = cmd.ExecuteReader
    While dr.Read()

    End While
    dr.Close()
    cn.Close()
    current = current.AddDays(1)
Next
```

It gets the data like it should, but I'm confused as to how I can put it into the RichTextBox's without using 30 odd IF statements.

Basically, it pulls data for Monday, then tuesday, then thursday, like that for 14 days. The text boxes are named "mon1", "mon2", "mon3"... "tues1", "tues2" etc... and I need to somehow get the data into all of them without having really poor and sloppy code.

Any help would be very much appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you change your text boxes so that they are named "Day0" thru "Day13", you can access them in your for loop like this:

```
For x = 0 to 13
  Me.Controls("Day" & x) = SomeValue
Next
```